# Can we create .java file using javap dissembler

Tags: java, javap

Can we regenerate .java file from .class file using javap tool of jdk?

I used `javap classsfile` command, it just prints .java file with data member and member functions declaration.

If not then what are the appropriate methods to accomplish it...

Comment: Note that you will be able to see some code but there is no guarantee that it will be same as original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot create complete .java file from javap tool.
javap tool only returns methods and members in class file.

you can use jad tool to decompile java code. but it also have limitations with code versions.

use http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JAD.shtml
to find jad tool

Answer (score 1):

generating .java from .class is called decompililng. So you need some decompiler to generate .java from .class

here are some of the open source decompiler

[link1](http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/)

[link2](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

[link3](http://downloads.phpnuke.org/en/download-item-view-g-v-v-g-v/DJ+JAVA+DECOMPILER.htm)

[link4](http://jdec.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible using java Decompiler.Please download java Decompiler or go through this url
http://jd.benow.ca/